# How to rename image file with Python？

Tags: python, image

My camera imported a background image. Is there any way to rename this image file with Python in Blender? That is, change its original name in Windows. Like "C_0V9.psd" to "C_0V1.psd".

[image: 1. List item]

------------------------------------------------------

PS：

Knowing that the command is os.rename(), is it possible to write a complete code for require a folder directory? For example, how to refine the following code?

```
import os
filepath='C:\\Work\\Working\\0Head\\ImageBackground1\\'
os.rename('C_0V9.psd','C_0V9.psd')
```

Comment: use `os.rename()` [learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python)

Comment: Thankfully, the full code is: import os
os.rename('C:\\Work\\Working\\0Head\\ImageBackground1\\C_0V9.psd', 'C:\\Work\\Working\\0Head\\ImageBackground1\\C_0V91.psd')

Comment: @leeblues If this code is enough, what do you use it for? It will leave a Blender image with a wrong path to file that no longer exists. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: yes，I have a other code at the same time modified bpy.data.images["C_0V9.psd"].filepath， Just want to add to modify the system name, and I added the question, how to improve the code please?

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

os.rename('C:\\Work\\Working\\0Head\\ImageBackground1\\C_0V9.psd', 'C:\\Work\\Working\\0Head\\ImageBackground1\\C_0V91.psd')
```